# How to kill Processes running under different users using c++ code

Tags: c++, kill-process

The following code works fine in displaying the process id of all the processes (eg: notepad.exe) running under different users. But process under current user is alone getting killed. I need to kill all the processes running under different users.

```
#define SAMPLEAPP "notepad.exe"
void main()
{
    KillProcessByName(SAMPLEAPP);
    system("pause");
}
void KillProcessByName(const char *filename)
{
    // Taking snapshot of all processes
    HANDLE hSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);
    //structure to capture each entry in snapshot
    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry;
    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof (pEntry);
    //capture the first process in the list
    BOOL hRes = Process32First(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
    while (hRes)
    {
        char tempProcess[PROCESS_SIZE];// = pEntry.szExeFile;
        wcstombs(tempProcess, pEntry.szExeFile, PROCESS_SIZE);
        //if process name is equal to the process passed as argument to be killed
        if (strcmp(tempProcess, filename) == 0)
        {
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0,
                (DWORD) pEntry.th32ProcessID);
            std::cout << "Process ID of the Process " << tempProcess << " is : " << pEntry.th32ProcessID;
            if (hProcess != NULL)
            {
                // Kill the process 
                TerminateProcess(hProcess, 9);
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        }
        //Capture the next process in process snapshot
        hRes = Process32Next(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnapShot);
}
```

How can I kill a process, even if it belongs to another user?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click your program, and then select "Run as administrator".

Comment: I've tried "Run as Administrator" also. Even then Processes under other users not getting killed.

Comment: Can the user account you're using terminate those processes using Task Manager?

Comment: Yes. From the Task Manager I'm able to end the processes of other users with the "End Process" option.

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` return when `TerminateProcess()` fails?